# Triger Embarcadero 10.2.3 Erreur ilink32

Tags: c++, builder, vcl, vcl-styles, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

i have a problem during the compilation.
"[ilink32 Erreur] Fatal: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier 'VCL.THEMEDACTNCTRLS.OBJ'"
Error impossible to open this file "vcl.themedactnctrls.obj"
I have look one the include file. The .cbproj and other.
I have try to delete or on the import project the C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\source\vcl.

Have you a answer or piste ?

Comment: Did you create the project with the VCL framework enabled to begin with? Usually you get these kind of errors when the VCL libraries are not being linked to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They need add the `#include<Vcl.ThemedActnCtrls.hpp>` 
this filed is here -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\include\windows\vcl